# Definitions of BSpline

Tags: spline

I can think of 4 ways of defining BSpline with separate, equally spaced knots:

1. recursion
2. convolution
3. sum
4. divided difference.

Methods 1 & 2 start with the indicator function of the unit interval.

Which of these generalise to nonseparate and/or non-equally spaced knots?

For the case of coallesced knots, can we take as on of our inital BSplines a Dirac delta $\delta(x-t_i)$?

Comment: Don't take for granted that we understand your terminology.

Comment: 1. and 4. surely do. 2. surely don't. and I have no idea what 3. sum is about.